# AppSetting values unavailable in Service Fabric cluster

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

My code is exactly the same as the code presented in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940710/getting-value-from-appsettings-json-in-net-core)(*but fixed*). The code runs fine in a standalone Web API project but when I add the same ASP.NET Core Web API project in a Service Fabric project template and run it on local cluster, `_mySettings` is always null. Is there something that I am missing here? I am using `Options<type>` approach. I can confirm that the `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")` evaluates to "Development", in my `HomeController` code.

The project targets .NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the reason why it doesn't work by default in a project which is newly created from Visual Studio solution template but [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52290750/19740040) fixed my issue.